# System.Data.Entity.DataBase can't be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I can't find `DataBase` in `System.Data.Entity`.

Any one know why?

Thank you.

Comment: you accepted the wrong answer. I know im pushing it here, but I answered it first (23 june < 29 june).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You dont have to import `System.Data.Entity.Database`. The `System.Data.Entity` is enough. 
Use `Database.SetInitializer` instead of `DbDatabase.SetInitializer`.

If you missed it it, the class is called Database without "Db"

Answer (score 8):

You need to reference the `EntityFramework.dll` assembly which is where the [Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class is declared. You could install it from the corresponding [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework).

Comment: the reference to EntityFramework was added to my project but i cant find DataBase in System.Data.Entity , System.Data.Entity Available but no DataBase in it.

Comment: @fligant, probably because the class is called `Database` and not `DataBase`. Notice the difference?

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Database its namespace not class, where i can use DbDatabase.SetInitializer

Comment: @fligant, no it's a class. Look at the documentation link I provided.

Comment: There was a change to the API from the CTP to the RTM regarding System.Data.Entity.Database.  Check which version of EntityFramework you're referencing.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem. Daz and Darin's answer gave me some clues.

In CTP, the class name is called "DbDatabase" in namespace System.Data.Entity.Database.

But in my version which is EF 4.1, the class is called "Database" and is in System.Data.Entity. System.Data.Entity.Database namespace is gone at least in EF4.1

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, you upgraded from Enterprise Library 4 CTP5 to Enterprise Library 4.1.

The namespaces changed a little and you will now find the classes you need in different namespaces. As shown in Kasper Skov's answer here, the `DbDatabase` class is now in `System.Data.Entity` and is renamed to `Database`.

I haven't yet worked out where IConfigurationConvention has moved to as `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Configuration` is another defunct namespace.

Answer (score 0):

On my version, Entity Framework 4.1.10715.0', `System.Data.Entity.Database` is a namespace and not a class.  `DbDatabase` IS a class in that namespace and it contains the `SeInitializer` method.  What a PITA to find when everything I've read contradicts this.

I had to use the following to get the Steven Sanderson demo to remake my database.

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.DbDatabase.SetInitializer(
    new System.Data.Entity.Database.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Mvc3ScaffoldDemo.Models.Mvc3ScaffoldDemoContext>());
```

Comment: @Bill mine is entity framework 4.1.10715.0 , installed by nuget .... System.Data.Entity.Database is a class not a namespace and have no DbDatabase .......

Answer (score 0):

Just update your Entity Framework to do that just right click on the solution and select "Manage NuGet Package" and search with "EntityFramework". install latest version ( 6.1.3 or ) or use " NuGet package console"  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpFJD.jpg)